# In bootstrap what is the acceptable way to change height of class="form-group" in a form?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="modal fade" >
 <form class="form-horizontal" ..>
  <div class="form-group ">
      then several ...
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-10 col-md-offset-2">
 <label class="control-label col-lg-4 col-md-4" for="BuildingCost">Cost</label>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 al-left">
    <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm has-feedback" required="required" min="5" aria-describedby="CostStatus" id="Cost" name="Cost"/>
    <span class="form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>   
    </div></div></div>
```

Using:
Bootstrap v3.3.4
Modernizr v2.6.2
jQuery JavaScript Library v2.1.3

Comment: I don't see a row

Comment: I like adding `padding` to the inputs. But I have fat fingers and get frustrated on mobile filling out forms. Just my $0.02.

Comment: Make that a <div class="form-group">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as "acceptable way". You can do it in many ways, all dependent only on the look you're after. If you're referring to best practices, the most appropriate choice is to create a utility class.

```
<div class="row really-tall">

</div>
```

The height itself can be increased with `height` or `min-height` attributes as well as anything that contributes to the overall height, such as `padding`:

```
.really-tall{ min-height: 600px; }
```

or

```
.really-tall{ padding-top: 100px; padding-bottom: 100px; }
```

Comment: Thank you. I was just wondering if there is a some what "normal" way this is accomplished given the classes, etc that Bootstrap utilizes. A util class is what I too would have chosen or if only needed in 1 or 2 areas a more direct change on those items.